# value of $\zeta(2+2i)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

What is the value of $\zeta(2+2i)$ ?

I am interested in the value of non real number of zeta function.

Comment: There is no reason to expect it has a closed form, if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: It is well known the value of $\zeta(n)$, where $n$ is integer.

Comment: So I wondered Gauss integer version.

Comment: Only for even integers. However, $2+2i$ is not an even integer.

Comment: Yes, closed form of $\zeta(2n+1)$ where $n>0$ is not known

Comment: There are some result for odd integer by Zudlin and Ramanujan, but it is not famous for results for Gauss integer...

Comment: So, are you interested in "a closed form" expression or in a numerical approximation here?

Comment: Yes, that I want to know. Please show me if there is closed form.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \zeta(2+2i) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2-2i}$$

which is about 0.87-0.28i

Comment: according to WolframAlpha, $0.86735182963599306498433134373508012832228522092447394466... -
0.27512723880785764861866064309963878366253792814598066053... i$